# Trading with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, simulation, algorithmic-trading

I am working on an Algorithmic Trading program in Python for learning purposes. Using Numpy, I am trying to maximize the speed of the core simulation logic:

```
    t=0
    size = Ticks.shape[0] #Ticks is a numpy array
    while t<size:

        if self.toLong(t): 
            self._Trader.Long(Ticks[t,3])
            t+=1
            while t<size:
                if self.toexitLong(t): 
                    self._Trader.exitLong(Ticks[t,3])
                    break
                t+=1

        elif self.toShort(t): 
            self._Trader.Short(Ticks[t,3])
            t+=1
            while t<size:
                if self.toexitShort(t): 
                    self._Trader.exitShort(Ticks[t,3])
                    break
                t+=1

        t+=1
```

Basically, I need to apply a function to every row in a 2D array, but the logic that is applied to the row is dependent on conditions set by logic on previous rows. Most of the time in this loop is consumed by looking up the value at Ticks[t,3]. I have considered using 
an iterator or a "np.applyalongaxis" and setting data members for conditions, but I'm not sure either is what I need. Its also worth noting that the other methods this function is calling use the indices they are passed to perform operations on the same array.

What is the most efficient (computational speed) way of running this loop using Numpy?

Comment: Not a speed optimization, but it looks like this could be written more clearly with a `for` loop and a `mode` variable indicating whether you're in the middle of a long, a short, or neither. Incrementing a loop counter in 5 places is highly error-prone.

Comment: Do you really need to increment `t` 1 by 1 and check at each step whether to enter or exit a long or short, or can you just directly compute the next timestep at which you'll take an action? You don't seem to access the `Ticks` array to decide whether to enter or exit an action.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you. I originally wrote this loop with a couple mode variables, but I realized I could save a few milliseconds by not checking mode with every iteration.

Although it may not be clear, the enter/exit methods are using the index passed to perform operations on the array. For example, the enter/exit signals could trigger when the average of the last 5 closing prices > x, so it would be necessary to check for a trigger at every `t`. I suppose I could calculate every enter/exit signal at every row, and then "simulate" after.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rewrite the code, so that you have a clear for-loop with a simple mode flag and if-else-switches for the mode.
2. Use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) for jit-compiling the whole function, which should give a speedup of 1-3 orders of magnitude.